# Save and restore window size and position when using HeaderBar

Tags: python, gtk3

In my application, I’d like to restore the position and sizes of my application windows after restart. Currently, I’m using `Gtk.Window.get_size()` and `Gtk.Window.get_position()` to obtain the size and position, and `Gtk.Window.resize()` and `Gtk.Window.move()` to restore them.

This worked at first, but now, I’ve changed the application to use `Gtk.HeaderBar`, and neither position nor size are correct anymore.

The documentation for `Gtk.Window.get_position()` [states](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gtk.Window.get_position) that this is expected behavior. It says

> The correct mechanism is to support the session management protocol (see the “GnomeClient” object in the GNOME libraries for example) and allow the window manager to save your window sizes and positions.

but I don‘t know how that works or how to implement it.

So, how do I save and restore the window position and size when using `HeaderBar`? A portable solution would be best, but at least X11 and probably Wayland should be supportable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been various issues with `gtk_window_get_size()`, `gtk_window_set_size()` and client side decorations that have been recently fixed for GTK+ 3.20 — see [the release notes for the 3.20 version](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/ch32s10.html).

Make sure you're using the latest stable version of GTK+ if you want to restore the size of the window, and that you never use the allocated size, but the size returned by `gtk_window_get_size()`. It's also important to note that you should not query the window's state during destruction, but whenever the state itself changes. See, for instance, the [Saving window state page on the GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/SaveWindowState).

As for the position: you should be aware that global coordinate systems are not available on Wayland (and Mir), and thus you cannot query the position of your window on the screen, nor set it manually on that windowing system.

The GnomeClient API has long since been deprecated, and state saving as part of the session management does not really work. The documentation needs to be fixed.